# Google Sheets: return multiple values of substring search

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-sheets

Lets say I had a sheet like this

|  | COLA | COLB | COLC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ROW1 | blah | blahbingo | blah |
| ROW2 | blahmagic | blah | blah |
| ROW3 | bingoblah | blah | magicblah |

And then I had a sheet like:

| R | C |  | Substrings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | magic |
|  |  |  | bingo |

What formula could I use to get that second sheet to do this:

| R | C |  | Substrings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ROW1 | COLB |  | magic |
| ROW2 | COLA |  | bingo |
| ROW3 | COLA |  |  |
| ROW3 | COLC |  |  |

I want to find everywhere in sheet1 that one of the substrings match a cell and then return row header and column header of that cell. I'm specifically using Google Sheets but also tagged excel since there is so much overlap btw the 2 products.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). You are asking to to get the row and column positions of matches, which is seldom useful information in itself. Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Comment: Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel have different feature sets. Please remove the [excel] tag. Its description explicitly states _"Questions with this tag should ONLY be about how Microsoft Excel interacts with a specific web application. General questions about Microsoft Excel are off-topic here but can be asked at Super User."_

Answer (score 0):

You can apply something like this:

```
=LAMBDA(data,FILTER(data,data<>""))(flatten(map(A1:D1000,LAMBDA(each,IF(REGEXMATCH(each,join("|", FILTER(H1:H100,H1:H100<>""))),"R"&ROW(each)&"C"&COLUMN(each),"")))))
```

Change the ranges. In my example H contains the words you want to look up

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of the row labels in column A, the column labels in row 1, and the matching value, use this pattern:

```
=arrayformula( 
  lambda( 
    rowLabels, columnLabels, data, searchKeys, 
    lambda( 
      row, col, data, queryStatement, 
      split( 
        query( 
          flatten(row & "→" & col & "→" & data), 
          queryStatement, 
          0 
        ), 
        "→" 
      ) 
    )(
      filter(rowLabels, len(rowLabels)), 
      filter(columnLabels, len(columnLabels)), 
      filter( filter(data, len(rowLabels)), len(columnLabels) ), 
      "where Col1 contains" & join( " or Col1 contains ", 
        filter("'" & searchKeys & "'", len(searchKeys)) 
      ) 
    )
  )(Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!B1:D1, Sheet1!B2:D, D2:D)
)
```

...where `D2:D` contains the search keys you want to match to the data.